# In the monaco-editor, can I control a context menu item's visibility with 'precondition'?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Using the monaco-editor's Editor.addEditorAction function, I want the added action to only be visible on certain conditions.  Can I use the precondition parameter for this?

How?

It has a type of string so not sure how to pass a variable that will evaluate to true or false...